# Frame of SKShapeNode is offset

Tags: swift, view, sprite-kit, scale, aspect-ratio

I am trying to add a `physicsBody` to an `SKShapeNode` that is a rectangle. I built my `PhysicsBody` using `fromEdgesWithLoop` using the `Node`'s frame as the `CGRect` to build it.

Using the debug option to show `PhysicsBody`, I see that it is actually not centered on my Sprite.

[image: PhysicsBody is offset]

I searched the web to find that I should use this:

```
scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
```

Sadly, I tried all `scaleMode`s and there are no differences.

I also verified my `GameScene`'s size and it fits the iPad2 screen (my target), 1024x720.

The `SKShapeNode` is a child of the Scene.

I tried to set the position of my node in the center of the `Scene` before adding a `PhysicsBody` with its frame, but this changed nothing. The node was already in the center of the scene.

```
myShape.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
myShape.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: myShape.frame)
```

Comment: Have you checked the anchor point of your rectangle sprite?

Comment: It looks like the shape node is not centered. Try using one of the init methods, such as `SKShapeNode(rectOfSize:size)`. @Stefan `SKShapeNode` doesn't have an anchor point.

Comment: I am not sure I understand, centered on what? The SKShapeNode is placed in the GameScene.sks (the editor), I dragged a ShapeNode and placed it on the Scene. It helps me visualise the distances to have in the editor. I can correctly test if a touch from touchesBegan is contained by my ShapeNode, but I cannot set it's physicsBody from it's frame. My goal is to add a wall around it so the nodes insides with not get out.

Comment: I did a couple of tests, I added those at the end of the question. Tests with the position of my ShapeNode. I centered it before creating the PhysicsBody but the rectangle is still off.

Comment: Try this `myShape.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: myShape.frame.size)`

Comment: @0x141E : Using a rectangle of frame.size, I get a rectangle that is correctly positioned (as it doesn't use the position of the frame but only it's size), but I don't want/need a rectangle, I need the border of the rectangle only (the edge).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The position of an Edge Loop is relative to the node it's attached to. In general, for an `edgeLoopFromRect`, the position is given by

```
edge_loop_position = node.position + rect.frame.origin
```

In this case, your physics body is offset by the position of `myShape`. One way to fix this issue is to attach the edge loop to the scene instead of the shape node:

```
self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: myShape.frame )
```

Alternatively, you can subtract the node's position from the frame's position with

```
let rect = CGRect(origin:CGPoint(x:myShape.frame.origin.x-myShape.position.x, y:myShape.frame.origin.y-myShape.position.y), size:myShape.frame.size)
myShape.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect:rect)
```

Comment: Thanks you VERY MUCH! I had no idea this is how edge_loop where positioned. This worked perfectly fine and really helped me a lot!